# php database table creation fails

Tags: php, mysqli

I use the following gist to make an OOP attempt to create a database connection:

https://gist.github.com/jonashansen229/4534794

It seems to work so far.

But the creation of the database table passed_exams fails.

Edit:

After recent comments and suggestions i updated my code:

```
require_once 'Database.php'; // the gist 4534794

class DatabaseSchema {

  public function createStudents() {
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    $mysqli = $db->getConnection();
    $create_students = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students (
      id INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      firstname VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
      lastname VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
      university VARCHAR(50)
    )';
    $result = $mysqli->query($create_students);
  }

  public function createPassedExams() {
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    $mysqli = $db->getConnection();
    $create_passed_exams = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS passed_exams (
      id INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
      student_id INT(6),
      FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    )';
    $result = $mysqli->query($create_passed_exams);
  }

}

$db_student = new DatabaseSchema();

$db_student->createStudents();
$db_student->createPassedExams();
```

When i look in the mysql console, only table students is created. 
Why is table passed_exams missing?

Comment: $db_student = new DatabaseSchema()   there is `;` missing at the end.

Comment: oh boy, thanks @Arsh, completely overlooked.

Comment: this is not OOP, so use DatabaseSchema::createStudents();

Comment: @Arsh, the issue still exists.

Comment: @StandardNerd  what is a error now ?

Comment: SERIOUSLY?! None can see he never runs the query?! Read the code again!

Comment: @Arsh, i don't get any error messages. the tables aren't just created..

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka  yes you are right , he never run the select query , and the $query_exams is not empty as there is a text in string.

Comment: Why is your fuctions static? They don't need to be

Comment: @Martin, yeah, you're right!

Comment: Turn on [PHP error logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) too .

Comment: yes, i did but strangely there are no error messages shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` column on your `students` table is `INT(6) UNSIGNED` but the `student_id` column on the `passed_exams` table is a **signed** `INT(6)`. Therefore the `FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(id) ON DELETE CASCADE` clause will fail with "Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint".

I advise you to implement some error handling so that you would see this error message rather than blindly continue executing code.

Answer (score 5):

You create the **string** to check `$query_students = 'SELECT ID FROM STUDENTS';`
but you never actually run this. Then u check the string if it is Empty, it will never be empty in your code.
What you should do is use the CREATE ... IF NOT EXISTS syntax of mysql, and not what you do here.

First example show the syntax https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

Comment: Totally agree with you. as the string has a text it is never empty and he is checking if it's empty or not if empty then run query .

Comment: Good call to reference the `CREATE ... IF NOT EXISTS` too.

Comment: i just updated my code. now the table student will be created but the table passed_exams is still missing.

Comment: for the last issue - the table passed_exams creation - the answer Matt provides was the solution. but is there a way to give you some credits for the answers you gave?

Comment: i guess, i should have closed the question and opened a new one. Sorry Malimovka, next time i will.